# How do I take a screenshot in SteamOS's Desktop Mode?

Tags: linux, screenshot, steam-os, steam-deck

I want to take a screenshot of my Steam Deck's desktop in SteamOS 3.3.1. Normally I can take a screenshot by pressing Steam + R1, but this shortcut doesn't work in Desktop Mode. I tried to manually set a screenshot button in Steam's controller configuration, (Steam > Settings > Controller > Desktop Configuration > {button} > Camera Icon), but the button seemingly did nothing.

How do I take a screenshot in SteamOS's Desktop Mode?

Comment: If you have a normal keyboard then the traditional Print Screen should work.

Answer (score 1):

I've been wondering the same thing as I've been using Greenshot.org on Windows, which isn't supported on Linux.

https://getgreenshot.org/faq/will-there-ever-be-a-greenshot-version-for-linux-or-mac/

Anyway I found another program called ksnip, which seems to do the job similar to Greenshot.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1155831)